# Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (93)

Tags: javascript, node.js, sass, gulp

Getting below error after installed latest node.js (v16.13.1)

> Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (93)
> For more information on which environments are supported please see:
> https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.14.1
> I have created static pages for my application and use sass and gulp

I have a static pages and using Sass in the page and use gulp to run on the browser.(npm install). Below are the version which worked my application:

- Node.js - 12.18.0
- gulp - "4.0.2"
- "gulp-sass": "4.1.0"

**Package.json file**

```
"scripts": {
              "start": "gulp watch"
    },
"dependencies": {
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "5.15.1",
        "@ttskch/select2-bootstrap4-theme": "^1.5.2",
        "bootstrap": "4.5.3",
        "bootstrap-datepicker": "^1.9.0",
        "jquery": "3.5.1",
        "jquery.easing": "^1.4.1",
        "select2": "^4.1.0-rc.0",
        "gulp": "4.0.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "browser-sync": "2.26.13",
        "del": "6.0.0",
        "gulp": "4.0.2",
        "gulp-autoprefixer": "7.0.1",
        "gulp-clean-css": "4.3.0",
        "gulp-header": "2.0.9",
        "gulp-plumber": "^1.2.1",
        "gulp-rename": "2.0.0",
        "gulp-sass": "4.1.0",
        "gulp-uglify": "3.0.2",
        "merge-stream": "2.0.0"
    }
```

Even using command `npm rebuild node-sass` is not changing anything.

Comment: Remove the **node_modules** folder and try running `npm install` again?

Comment: No Hope:-
C:\Users\Ranjan.Singh\ranjan\Project\Syne\syneAdmin\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\Ranjan.Singh\ranjan\Project\Syne\syneAdmin\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',

Comment: In my case, I had to upgrade node, npm and sass-loader to the latest versions to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gulp-sass 4.1.0 uses [node-sass 4](https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass/blob/v4.1.0/package.json#L29), and node-sass 4 does not support Node.js 16, as indicated in [this table](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/#node-version-support-policy).

To support Node.js 16, upgrade gulp-sass: the latest version today is [5.1.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass/v/5.1.0):

```
npm install -D gulp-sass@5.1.0
```

This will give you node-sass 7, which supports all current versions of Node.js, including Node.js 16.

Comment: It worked. Run the above command and add line on gulpfile.js
const sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));
Thank you so much

Comment: Happy to help :)